# Sequence of functions on an object

Tags: r

In R, is there a recommended way to apply a list of functions to an object, such that the output of the (n-1)th function is inserted into the nth function?

For example, say I had a list of functions for cleaning a character string; and I wanted to apply all of them to the same unclean string, for example:

```
mystring <- "ImPortant info - some extra";
cleaning_functions <- 
  list(function(s){tolower(s)}, 
       function(s){substr(s, 1, grep(' -') -1)})
```

And the net result would be: `"important info"`.
This can be achieved with a loop; but I'm hoping for a "plyr"-esque solution.
If it so happens that a loop is efficient, so be it; but I'd be surprised if it was optimal.

Note that for my final solution the order of operations is important, the provided list of functions will be dynamically created and potentially unnamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [*function composition*](https://github.com/klmr/functional#function-composition). There are many ways to skin the cat. The easiest is to write a simple wrapper, or to use an existing library (see e.g. link):

```
compose = function (f, g) {
    function (...) f(g(...))
}
```

And then apply it to your problem:

```
cleaning_functions = do.call(compose, cleaning_functions)
# or, directly
cleaning_functions = compose(tolower, function (s) substr(s, 1, regexpr(' -', s) - 1))
```

And call it like any function:

```
cleaning_functions(my_string)
```

Comment: Actually, it's not clear that this works. I'm getting infinite recursion errors even with just one level of composition. Any thoughts?

Comment: @jameselmore No idea what you’re doing. There’s definitely no infinite recursion here. That said, your example function contained an error (but it doesn’t lead to infinite recursion). But once that’s fixed, the code I wrote works exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Generate some test functions:

```
test1 <- function(x){paste(x,"a",sep="")}
test2 <- function(x){paste(x,"b",sep="")}
test3 <- function(x){paste(x,"c",sep="")}
test4 <- function(x){paste(x,"d",sep="")}
test5 <- function(x){paste(x,"e",sep="")}
```

Then call those functions:

```
string <- "test"
for (i in c("test1","test2","test3","test4","test5")) {
  string <- do.call(i, list(string))
}
string
[1] "testabcde"
```

---

For your concrete example the following should work:

```
mystring <- "ImPortant info - some extra"
cleaning_functions <- 
   list(function(s){tolower(s)}, 
      function(s){substr(s, 1, regexpr(' -', s) - 1)})
for (i in cleaning_functions) {
   mystring <- do.call(i, list(mystring))
}
mystring
[1] "important info"
```

Note that I had to change the `grep` to `regexpr` for it to work.

Comment: My list of functions will be dynamically created else where, and they are not guaranteed to be named.

Comment: How are the dynamically created functions stored, if they are not named?

Comment: try the example I gave.. functions are objects and need not be named:
`(cleaning_functions[[1]])('ALLCAPS')`
will return `"allcaps"`

Comment: Much better; thanks. I've changed down-vote to up-vote. This is similar to the approach I'm using now, but I'm hoping for a more efficient answer (if one exists). I'll let the question sit for a bit and if there isn't any action after a while I'll give you the "Accept"

Comment: Don't think it can actually be improved computationally as the functions need to be applied sequential. But I also wouldn't know how this would work, if the sequence does not matter.